# Replace the existing plot in matplotlib instead of making a new figure inside a loop for imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, python-imaging-library, seaborn

I want to save the displayed images according to the given input by user but the problem is that **unlike plt.other_plots(), plt.imshow() does not overwrite the existing figure** but makes a new figure with under the existing one. How can I replace the existing one?

I have tried many methods but none seem to work such as `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook` with

```
plt.ion()
plt.show()
for i in range(5): 
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(50,50))  # plot the figure
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    x = input()
    #my_fun(x) # that has it's independent working so
```

or

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(5):
  plt.imshow(np.random.rand(50,50))
  plt.show()
  x = input()
  # my_fun(x)
```

I have also used `plt.subplots(1,1)` / `plt.figure()` inside and outside the loops,  `Ipython.display()` and `Ipython.display.Image`.

Nothing seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You can always save your figures as .png files:

```
for i in range(5):
    plt.imshow(np.random.rand(50,50))
    plt.savefig('file_name_{}.png'.format(i))
```

Comment: saving figure is not same as saving images.